# Shechiyanu on seeing Kotel

Tags: blessing, kotel-western-wall

The [Rivevos Ephraim 4:54:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1535&st=&pgnum=129) wonders if one says a shechiyanu upon seeing the kotel for the first time,and he brings a source who quotes the opinion of Rav Kook who held one is obligated to make a Shechiyanu upon the first time. The Rivevos Ephraim is mesupak if anyone argues on this,does anyone else speak about this?

Rav Mordechai Fogelman in his [Beis Mordichai siman 32](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21514&st=&pgnum=67) writes that one should make a shechiyanu as well.

Comment: What is significant about the Kotel??

Comment: That's a good question,I don't really unrest and why one would make one,that's why I asked if someone else speaks about this ,I would never have wondered this

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25987/discussion-on-question-by-sam-shechiyanu-on-seeing-kotel).